# Where does this energy equation come from: $E_k=k\frac{k(q_1q_2)}{r}$

Tags: electrostatics

I have this equation but I have no idea where it came from.

$E_k=k\frac{(q_1q_2)}{r}$

I don't understand especially since I have this other equation:

$E = k\frac{Q_{source}}{r^2}$

And cannot find any relation between the two. Please any helps or suggestions would be useful. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have researched this and either am looking in the wrong place or just can't find it anywhere so please help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is electrostatic potential energy, the second on is electric field. You can tell they are supposed to represent different physical quantities because they have different units.

I am pretty sure that the way it is presented in your textbook, the second equation for the electric field is to be seen as justified by experiment and you will derive other things, for example, the first equation, from it.